# What is best practice for signal handling in production multi-threaded program on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, signals

I'm writing a multi-threaded program that shall run on a Linux system. I want to be sure that, if the program was in a reliable running condition (i.e. no segmentation faults, no abort, etc...), on exit it finalises a file writing some trailing information. To do so I want to handle the [termination signals](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-Signals.html) in order to trigger a graceful shut down.
Since it is a multi-threaded program all the signals are masked for all the threads but the main, which call sigwait on a signal set filled only with the termination signals. So all other signals are handled by their default action.

Is this a good practice, or I should provide a custom action for every signal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this a good practice,

Yes absolutely. Handling termination signals in a multi-threaded environment any other way(by not having a single thread responsible for them) is virtually impossible.

> or I should provide a custom action for every signal?

No. You'd normally want to handle SIGINT, SIGTERM and SIGHUP. SIGKILL can't be handled, and I'd leave SIGQUIT alone so it could be used to core-dump the application.

Comment: I'd add SIGPIPE to the list of signals that you might legitimately handle, but it does depend on your program.  It is often a good idea to ignore SIGPIPE so that you get a write error instead of an interrupt when you write to a pipe which has no process reading from it.

Answer (score 0):

Use signalfd()!

This lets you handle signals along with file descriptor readiness in a single select() call.

Comment: Even if your answer is not really related to the question, I thank you for it! signalfd seems to be a more flexible solution with respect to either sigwait and pselect, since allows more control on different signal sets.

Indeed, it is possible to assign a signal set to a file descriptor and then multiplex all the needed file descriptors to select, easing signal handling. No need for globals and callbacks :)